# Show by an example that in computer arithmetic a + (b + c) may differ from (a + b) + c

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, computer-science

**Show by an example that in computer arithmetic a + (b + c) may differ from (a + b) + c**

Here is what I am thinking, but I am not really sure. Maybe someone can lead me in the right direction or tell me if my answer is sufficient.

What I was thinking was it is true that:

$a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$ in normal arithmetic:

For example: $5 + (-2 + 7) = 10$ & similarly $(5 - 2) + 7 = 10$

Yet in computer arithmetic this isn't the case..
For example:

$\infty + (- \infty + 1) = 0$ But here we find that $(\infty + - \infty) + 1 = 1$

$\therefore$ in regards to computer arithmetic $a + (b + c) \ne (a + b) + c$

Comment: What computer languages can add and subtract infinities?

Comment: I'm really confused. I must have a different idea of what "computer arithmetic" means.

Comment: This is how floating point arithmetic not being equivalent was explained to me in a class. I wasn't sure if this is what they were looking for or not. I'm not sure if the inifnities are supposed to represent booleans or I'm not really sure. Any guidance would be great though.

Comment: $\infty+(-\infty)$ is NaN in IEEE754, so your example is false.

Comment: Two good links on floating point and associativity: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5380 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a case where
$a+(b+c)
\ne (a+b)+c
$,
consider a case
when $b+c$ overflows
but $a = -b$
so
$(a+b)+c
= c$
which is a normal result.

Comment: Can you give an example with numbers so I can see what you mean exactly?

Comment: if $b+c$ overflows, then (-b)+(b+c) underflow, resulting that $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$. You can check in C that $(-2000000000+200000000)+100000000=-2000000000+(200000000+100000000)=1000000000$

Answer (score 0):

In floating point you can have $b$ smaller than the resolution of $a$ (meaning that it is too small to change the last bit in the mantissa of $a$) and hence get $a+b=a$, if you take $b=c$ then $(a+b)+c=(a+b)+b=a+b=a$. But if $b+c$ is not smaller than the resolution of $a$ then $a+(b+c)\neq a$.

Actual number depend on the language, floating point type and operating system.

Comment: Another example is $(a,b,c)=(-9007199254740990.0,9007199254740991.0,9007199254740990.0)$ in IEEE double precision. can be verified in c/c++ using double type or in python.

Comment: @TerenceHang -  A simpler example is $(a,b,c) = (0.1,0.2,0.3)$.